# Error 70 permission denied when Open Statement (I/O) runs to check if a .pdf file is open

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-pdf

In order to export an Excel Workbook to .PDF file, I'm getting the error 70 permission denied when the .PDF file is already created and opened.

Error comes in this line of the code below:

```
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
```

I tried to modify the Open statement (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) by changing the mode (Required. Keyword specifying the file mode: Append, Binary, Input, Output, or Random. If unspecified, the file is opened for Random access.) and the lock (Optional. Keyword specifying the operations restricted on the open file by other processes: Shared, Lock Read, Lock Write, and Lock Read Write.). But I'm still getting the error.

```
Sub exportPDF_Click()

    Dim filename, filePath, PathFile As String
    filename = "Name of the File"
    filePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    If Len(filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    PathFile = filePath & "\" & filename & ".pdf"
    ' Check if file exists, prompt overwrite
    If existFile(PathFile) Then

        If MsgBox("The file already exists." & Chr (10) & "Overwrite 
        existing file?", _
          vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Existing File") = vbNo Then

            Do
            PathFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
            (InitialFileName:=filePath, _
                FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
                Title:="Select a folder and a name to save the
                file."

            ' Handle cancel
            If PathFile = False Then Exit Sub

            ' Loop if new filename still exists
            Loop While existFile(PathFile)
        End If
    End If

    If fileOpened(PathFile) Then
        GoTo errHandler
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            filename:=PathFile, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=True
    End If

    Exit Sub

errHandler:
        ' Display a message stating the file in use.
        MsgBox "The PDF file was not created." & Chr (10) & Chr (10) & 
        filename & ".pdf" & "has been opened by another user!"

End Sub

'=============================
Function existFile(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
  existFile = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
End Function
'=============================
'=============================
Function fileOpened(PathFile As String)

' Test to see if the file is open.
fileOpened = IsFileOpen(PathFile)
End Function
'=============================
'=============================

' This function checks to see if a file is open or not. If the file is
' already open, it returns True. If the file is not open, it returns
' False. Otherwise, a run-time error occurs because there is
' some other problem accessing the file.

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum '<--- error line
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
'=============================
```

The expected result is a MsgBox saying:

"The PDF file was not created.

Name of the File.pdf has been opened byanother user!"

What I'm missing here?

Comment: you've commented out the "case else" just before "Error errnum" at the bottom of the code so the process falls through to the error errnum if the file is open. And that line should read RaiseError errnum anyway.

Comment: Sorry about that @HarassedDad. I fixed it but error is still there. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: `Loop While existFile(PathFile)` looks suspicious. You're continuing the `Do` loop which prompts the user to get a new filename/path, but within that loop you're not checking whether file is open.

Comment: Thank you @DavidZemens. I fixed the code. Please let me know if you can reproduce the error now.

Comment: Nope. I'm getting an err.Number = 53 if the file doesn't exist. If the file does exist, then I get an err.Number = 13 at `If PathFile = False Then Exit Sub`.

Comment: err.Number 53 is fixed by changing Open mode from Input to Random.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do here. One problem is that you're allowing user to specify a new filename, but then not checking whether that file exists or is writeable, etc. There are some other possible errors I noted in comments above, for example you can't compare `PathFile = False` without raising a Type 13 mismatch, and if you pass the name of non-existent file you might get a 53 Bad FileName or Number in the `IsFileOpen` function.

Get rid of `fileOpened`, that serves no purpose except as a wrapper to `IsFileOpen`, so just use `IsFileOpen` instead. Get rid of the clumsy `On Error` in your main procedure. We can of course add targeted error-handling back in if needed, but I think it's not needed.

I've compartmentalized/refactored the code below, and I think this will solve the problem. In particular I wrote another function `fileIsWriteable` and use that to wrap the `existFile` and `IsFileOpen` functions, as well as the message box prompts.

The main procedure then calls this function against the initial `PathFile`. If the file is not writeable, then we call another new function `getNewFileName` which ensures that the user chooses a writeable (either unlocked, or non-existent) filename.

I think it is self-explanatory, but let me know if I need to clarify.

```
Option Explicit

Sub exportPDF_Click()

Dim filename$, filePath$, PathFile$
Dim fdlg As FileDialog
filename = "Book1"
filePath = "C:\debug\"
Dim mb As VbMsgBoxResult
If Len(filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub

PathFile = filePath & "\" & filename & ".pdf"

If Not fileIsWriteable(PathFile) Then
    ' File is NOT writeable.
    PathFile = getNewFileName(filePath)
End If
If Len(PathFile) > 0 Then
    ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=PathFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End If
End Sub

Function fileIsWriteable(filePath As String) As Boolean
Dim mb As VbMsgBoxResult
    If existFile(filePath) Then
        If IsFileOpen(filePath) Then
            MsgBox filePath & "has been opened by another user!"
            fileIsWriteable = False
        Else
            mb = MsgBox(filePath & " already exists." & Chr(10) & "Overwrite existing file?", _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Existing File")
            fileIsWriteable = mb = vbYes
        End If
    Else
        ' file either doesn't exist, or exists but isn't open/locked, so we should
        ' be able to write to it:
        fileIsWriteable = True
    End If
End Function

Function getNewFileName(filePath As String) As String
Dim fn$
Do
    fn = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
            InitialFileName:=filePath, _
            FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
            Title:="Select a folder and a name to save the file.")
    If fn = "False" Then Exit Function
Loop While Not fileIsWriteable(fn)
getNewFileName = fn
End Function

Function existFile(rsFullPath As String) As Boolean
  existFile = CBool(Len(Dir$(rsFullPath)) > 0)
End Function

Function IsFileOpen(filename As String)
' This function checks to see if a file is open or not. If the file is
' already open, it returns True. If the file is not open, it returns
' False. Otherwise, a run-time error occurs because there is
' some other problem accessing the file.
Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum '<--- error line
Close filenum          ' Close the file.
errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

' Check to see which error occurred.
Select Case errnum

    ' No error occurred.
    ' File is NOT already open by another user.
    Case 0
     IsFileOpen = False

    ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
    ' File is already opened by another user.
    Case 70
        IsFileOpen = True

    ' Another error occurred.
    Case Else
        Err.Raise errnum
End Select

End Function
```

**NB:** I think this would be further improved by using an `Application.FileDialog` instead of `Application.GetSaveAsFileName` but I don't remember how to enforce the file filters with that method.

Comment: I really appreciate the time you took to answer my question. Your code improves mine without doubts but error 70 is still there. Another malfunction I found is when you canceling the overwriting of the file, generates it anyway. I think you catch what I'm trying to do with this macro too.

Comment: The logic should be something like this:

> If the file does not exist then create a new one.

> If the file exists then:
1) If the file is open then show message informing that the file is open.
2) If the file is closed then:
Ask to overwrite the file with the same name.
1) If the answer is YES then:
Overwrite file.
2) If the answer is NO then:
Offer the possibility of saving the file with another name.

Comment: OK, I made a few revisions. I'm not sure about your Error 70 -- it's possible you have the debug option set to break on all errors? This is in the VBE under Tools>Options>General and make sure you have set to "Break on unhandled errors", not "Break on All Errors".

Comment: It was that! My bad for not check this out before. Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Comment: Do consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it has been helpful for you. Cheers.